# MediaPlayer class listening for NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan change

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing a custom audio player in c# using the MediaPlayer class. I have implemented a scroll bar so the user can seek through a track and this is where I am having the problem.

WHen the user selects an audio track (loaded from an xml playlist) the app calculates the length in seconds of the track and sets this as the max value for the scroll bar. This all works fine except the **NaturalDuration.TimeSpan** property sometimes returns 0 rather than the amount. I have proved this by adding a loop that exits when **NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan** is true then returns the NaturalDuration.TimeSpan value.

My question is how can I just get the **NaturalDuration.TimeSpan** when the **NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan** is changed to true?

Comment: Not sure i get this... If you want to do something when hastimespan is changed just use inpc or some other handler for change. Or do you want to get timespan after setting hastimespan to true manually?

Comment: Inpc? ANd fromw what I can tell there isn't a handler that notifies of a change of hastimespan. I basically want to add my own listener to that variable changing - if possible.

Comment: [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

Comment: But doesnt the built MediaPlayer class need to implement that? Or does it and that's what you're saying...

Comment: There is a way more resource-intensive solution that uses reflections i believe (will look for the link if all else fails), though this might not be necessary at all. Any idea why it doesn't always return properly? And what would you do even if you had the handler?

Comment: At the point of hastimespan being true I can get the total amount of seconds of the piece of audio has and set the max value on my seek bar. I guess the MediaPlayer class just takes a few milliseconds to calculate the length of the track.

Comment: Oh, i see... Hmm... Try overriding HasTimeSpan so it raises propertychanged :).

Comment: Or even better - do it for `TimeSpan` and bind to it.

Comment: How do I do that? Override TimeSpan i mean.

Comment: [Here is the override reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to handle the `MediaPlayer.MediaOpened` event:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(mediaFilePath, UriKind.Absolute));

...

private void MediaPlayer_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.HasTimeSpan)
    {
        SliderMaximum = mediaPlayer.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        mediaPlayer.Play();
    }
}
```